# Transfer nft with anchor-link

Tags: transfer, nft

I use this repository to connect to Anchor-Wallet while trying to transfer nfts:

[anchor-link](https://github.com/greymass/anchor-link/blob/master/examples/login/index.html)

When I send the transaction, in the console I have this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) exception: Account not found at /v1/chain/get_abi

Here is the code I am using:

```
function transfer() {
        const action = {
            account: 'eosio.nft',
            name: 'transfer',
            authorization: [session.auth],
            data: {
                from: session.auth.actor,
                to: 'receiver.wam',
                 asset_ids: '123456789',
                memo: 'Anchor is the best! Thank you <3'
            }
        }
        session.transact({action}).then((result) => {
            document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += `Transaction broadcast! ${ result.processed.id }\n`
        })
    }
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that either the rpc-endpoint or the chainId you configured is incorrect.

```
    const link = new AnchorLink({
        transport,
        chains: [{
            chainId: 'aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906',
            nodeUrl: 'https://eos.greymass.com',
        }]
    })
```

will only work on EOS as it's the EOS-chainId and a EOS-Node behind the nodeUrl.

for other chains, like WAX it would be

```
    const link = new AnchorLink({
        transport,
        chains: [{
            chainId: '1064487b3cd1a897ce03ae5b6a865651747e2e152090f99c1d19d44e01aea5a4',
            nodeUrl: 'https://wax.greymass.com',
        }]
    })
```

You can find the necessary information about chainId's and endpoints on [validate.eosnation.io](https://validate.eosnation.io/) .